# MySQL 5.6 DESTDIR not work propely

Tags: mysql

I'm try compiling MySQL 5.6 from source in Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

But when I execute `make install DESTDIR="/etc/mysql"`, not work was expected.

MySQL is installed in `/etc/mysql/usr/local/mysql`.

What's wrong?

*Sorry for my english*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DESTDIR](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#DESTDIR) is a variable inserted at the beginning of each target file

If you wanted to install MySQL in the /usr/local/mysql, you could use the following command sequence

```
cd /name/of/source/directory
make clean
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql
make && make install
```

MySQL would thus be installed in the /usr/local/mysql directory.

The ./configure allows you to control and define how your program will be installed and what options will be included or excluded.

[MySQL Source Configuration Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/source-configuration-options.html)